# Lagrangian having an $O(N)$ symmetry

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, complex-numbers

A Lagrangian with $SO(N)$ symmetry can be written like:

$${\mathcal{L}} = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \Phi)^T (\partial^\mu \Phi) - (\frac{1}{2}\mu^2 \Phi^T  \Phi + \frac{1}{4}\lambda (\Phi^ T \Phi)^2).$$

where $$\Phi =\begin{bmatrix} \phi_1 \\ \phi_2\\ \vdots \\ \phi_N \end{bmatrix}.$$

What additional terms can be included if Lagrangian need only to be $O(N)$ symmetric? How a Lagrangian of this form will look like in $O(N)$ symmetry? Do we need to replace the "transpose" with "dagger" (due to component fields in $\Phi$ becoming complex and also the "$1/2$" terms in Lagrangian to be corrected following that). Is this the only change it can have?

Now if I want a $SU(3)$ symmetric Lagrangian is the following correct?

$${\mathcal{L}} = (\partial_\mu \Phi)^\dagger (\partial^\mu \Phi) - (\mu^2 \Phi^\dagger  \Phi + \lambda (\Phi^\dagger \Phi)^2).$$

where $$\Phi =\begin{bmatrix} \phi_1 \\ \phi_2\\ \phi_3 \end{bmatrix}$$ with all $\phi_i$'s being complex?

Comment: You have to be more specific about the "name of the game" I think. For instance, am I allowed to add a (complex) scalar field that is in itself invariant under the $O(N)$ symmetry, and hence add a kinetic term $(\partial^{\mu} \chi^*)(\partial_{\mu}\chi)$ and another interaction term $g(\Phi^T\Phi)(\chi^*\chi)$?

Comment: Also, why not add terms of the form $\lambda' (\Phi^T\Phi)^4$ etc etc?

Comment: For the time being don't introduce other fields and don't go beyond $\phi-4$ theory.

Comment: Then I think all you can have is this...

Comment: You can also play around with the spatial derivatives if you want more Lagrangians. You typically also assume Lorentz/Euclidean invariance, but this still gives you quite a lot of different alternatives.

Comment: @schris38 Can you please complete the sentence. I didn't get what you meant by 'this'.

Comment: I mean the Lagrangian you have written in the post

Comment: O$(N)$ contains SO$(N)$, so if you want to impose O$(N)$, SO$(N)$ must be there too.